# Taxonomy term doesn't show up in admin/structure/taxonomy/manage/tags/overview

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I migrated a Drupal 6 site to Drupal 8.  Current running version is:  8.5.3
I created 4 terms in the Tag taxonomy and referenced in the content type Article.

The terms, however, do not show up in the overview page.

> [image: OverView Page]

They are in the database.

> [image: DB Select]

They are also visible when creating nodes.

> [image: Node create]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Do they have a parent value of 0 in the term hierarchy table, do they have entries in the term hierarchy table? That will do it. That table just needs the tid and parent value of '0'. Try it by adding one of the tag term tids to that table, clear the cache and reload that page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like they are missing parent value of 0 in the term hierarchy table. That will do it. That table just needs the tid and parent value of '0'. Try it by adding one of the tag term tids to that table, clear the cache and reload that page. This is easy to miss in migrations.

Comment: I'm adding terms through D8, but the tid nor parent is inserted into the taxonomy_term_hierarchy table.  Is there a setting I'm missing from migration that's broke this functionality somehow?